# How to dynamically load Page from xaml file/resource?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dynamic, loading

In codebehind, I need to load a Page object from XAML resource, and I explicitly need the result to be an instance of object of Page class. I have searched around and found some solutions involving XamlReader and such, but they all looked a bit weird and complicated, almost like hacks. Is there any simple and "normal" way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Page p = (Page)Application.LoadComponent(new Uri(@"relative/uri/to/xaml/file.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

[see msdn reference page for few more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.loadcomponent.aspx)

Comment: @tnw I was doing the usual "pre-question" research, and couldn't find anything really useful even on SO, as I wrote in the question itself, just some very hacky and needlessly complicated solutions. Then I stumbled by accident on this solution which seems to be the cleanest, simplest and most correct solution. Also a single one that is just one line. I decided to add the q+a to SO in a formulation that would have been useful for me when I was searching, so the site wouldn't have to fail someone who will be looking for this info after me. What exactly is suspicious or wrong about that?

Comment: Also, what exactly is opinion-based on stating an example of a command/function call, and a link to official language&platform dev's documentation page which pretty much explains that the method is **designed and intended** to perform just the thing the question asked?

Comment: Silverlight has only one version of LoadComponent (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms596995.aspx) so you have to use something like Page p = new Page(); Application.LoadComponent(p, new Uri("YourAssemblyName;component/yourpagesfolder/somepage.xaml", UriKind.Relative)); and your Page element needs to be the root element at the xaml file

Comment: ...correction to my previous comment, it's /YourAssemblyName e.g. new Uri("/MyApp;component/Pages/MyPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)